# Prompting User to Guess A Number Function

Tags: python, function, if-statement

The program is suppose to generate a random number between 0 and 10 and then prompt the user to guess it within five tries.  But the program continuously outputs " You guessed incorrect".  I've tried it out various times and it just keeps printing " You guessed incorrect" repeatedly for five tries.  How do I prompt it to say " You guessed Correct" when the user has the right number?

```
import random
def guess():
    randNum = random.randint(0,10)
    count = 0
    while count < 5:
        count = count + 1
        number1 = input("Guess A Number")
    if number1 != randNum:
       print(" You Guessed incorrect")
    else:

        print(" You are Correct")
```

Comment: `number1 = int(input("Guess A Number"))` You have to change the input type to an int.

Comment: Your input is a string; your random number is an integer.  These can never be equal.  Use `int(input("Guess a number"))` instead.

Comment: Also, you have to check the number *inside* the loop, not after all 5 guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation error. And you need to convert the guess into an `int` to compare it to `randNum`. And you probably want to `break` after a correct answer. Try this:

```
import random


def guess():
    randNum = random.randint(0,10)
    count = 0
    while count < 5:
        count = count + 1
        number1 = int(input("Guess A Number: "))
        if number1 != randNum:
            print(" You Guessed incorrect")
        else:
            print(" You are Correct")
            break
    print("The number was: " + str(randNum))


guess()
```